# Create folder with version and date

Tags: batch-file

First question here. I've used batch files for automating a lot of action but this one is getting really difficult.

Imagine I have a folder (lets call it 'ProjectFolder') and I have some folders inside this project folder (lets call them 'data', 'tools, 'trash') and each of these folders have files.
What I want is to create inside the 'ProjectFolder' a 'backup' folder and inside this one a folder called 'v001_date_time_user' and copy folders 'data' and 'tools' inside this folder. 
Then I run this script again to make a new version and it creates 'v002_date_time_user' and copies the same 'data' and 'tools' folders and files again.

What I can do now is create a folder called 'v_date_time_user' inside the 'backup' folder but I have no idea how to create the version part with 3 digits.

This is my code for now:

```
@echo off & setlocal enableextensions

:: variables
set dateNtime="[%date:~6,6%-%date:~3,2%-%date:~0,2%]_[%time:~0,2%-%time:~3,2%]"
set backup="backup"

set /A version=000

set backupcmd=xcopy /s /c /d /e /h /i /r /k /y

:: check for existence of [backup]
:: if [backup] doesn't exist, create it
if not exist "%backup%\" (
  echo folder "%backup%" not found
  echo creating folder "%backup%"
  md "%backup%" 
  )

:: create version folder with version number_date_hour_user
md "%backup%\v%version%_%dateNtime%_[%USERNAME%]"

:: copy older version into newer version
xcopy "data" "%backup%\v%version%_%dateNtime%_[%USERNAME%]\data" /E /C /I /H /Q 
xcopy "tools" "%backup%\v%version%_%dateNtime%_[%USERNAME%]\tools" /E /C /I /H /Q
```

can anyone help?
thanks
Luís

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple of ways I can think of.  You could loop through every folder beginning with a v and a number, and count them.  Then if you're starting with 000 then the number of matches will be your next number.

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
:: if you're starting with 001 rather than 000, then set count=1 instead of 0 here.
set count=0
pushd "path\to\ProjectFolder\backup"
for /f %%I in ('dir /b v* ^| findstr "^v[0-9][0-9][0-9]"') do set /a count=!count!+1
popd
set count=00%count%
set count=%count:~-3%
```

Then `%count%` will be your next number.

Another way would be to loop through `dir /b /o:n` (alphabetic sorting) and capture the last directory name, presumably v### with the highest number.  Then grab the first four characters of that capture and chop off the v.

Comment: It's working perfectly rojo! thanks for your help. Really thanks. You saved me hours of work.